# NSInteger to const char *

Tags: objective-c, cgcontext, uiprintpagerenderer

I am handed a `(NSInteger) pageIndex` and need to print that on a page with

`void CGContextShowTextAtPoint (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   const char *string,
   size_t length
);`

how do I get the `const char *string` and not to forget the length of that string

I tend to end up with nasty tricks to convert the integer to a string first and then do `cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` but that can't be the most elegant way

for completeness, here is the code

```
const char *pageIndexString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pageIndex] cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(CGContextRef, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, pageIndexString, strlen(pageIndexString));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", pageIndex];
const char *str = [tmp UTF8String];
size_t length = [tmp length];
```

Comment: that is basically what I did... not elegant, nasty and ugly. For completeness, I edited the question and pasted in the code.

Comment: @user1765406 maybe yes. What's wrong with that? Also, why do you use the Mac Roman encoding?

Comment: yes, I was quite surprised at the fact that I had to use `MacRoman`, but that was what I more or less understood from the [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html%23](Drawing with Quartz 2D Reference). Correct me if I do it wrong and if I could draw UTF text... that would be better

Comment: `%ld` should be the format specifier for an `NSInteger`. @user: The other solution is even uglier, involving `sprintf()` and `calloc()`.

Comment: odly enough, my compiler doesn't complain about %d - or is that due to iOS and OS-X differences

Comment: @Th.J. Maybe yes, but IMHO that's still UB, isn't it?

Comment: @H2CO3: NSObjCRuntime.h (line 399): `typedef int NSInteger;` --- that might explain the warning

Comment: @Th.J. Cool. In this case, use either `%d` or `%ld` and cast to the appropriate integral type in order to avoid UB arising from type promotion (which takes place since `- [NSString stringWithFormat:]` is a variadic method.